# I would like to merge SIP call and GSM call and make conference

Tags: android, asterisk, sip, voip, gsm

I would like to merge GSM call and SIP call. Let me elaborate. Suppose I have three device let say A, B and C. I have called B device from A through VOIP then B make GSM call to C. I would like to establish conference between them

Answer (score 1):

You can read app_confbridge.c in asterisk.org project source or  similar file in freeswitch source tree.
Task is not trivial.

In your case it even more complex becuase while you in gsm call you can't do sip on same phone on android(for security reason, blocked in kernel).

Or you can install asterisk/freeswitch on server, use gsm gate and create conference.

Comment: We are already using asterisk on server, but how do i merge the call?

Comment: Above article is for merging two SIP calls, my requirement is to merge SIP and GSM call. Please let me know if you have any solution

Comment: Asterisk doesn't care where the call comes from.  A GSM call, a SIP call and a POTS call are all the same internally to Asterisk.  You'll need a GSM gateway to connect your Asterisk box directly to the cellular network, but after that it's the same.

If you want someone to give you a "step-by-step, key-by-key" how-to, that's a consulting job.  This site is to help you fix your own build that isn't working quite right.

Comment: Source of call doesn't metter. That method connect channels on channel level(connect sounds)

Comment: But i would like to make Android phone as GSM gateway. Guys, please read my post carefully

Comment: Sure. But google developers do their best so you can't do that on android phone. Sorry to inform you, but you need have much more level to hack that.

Comment: In other words i would like to merge SIP call and GSM call. You can say i would like to do conference call

Comment: Let say it clear word. You want create low cost voip termination device. Main goal of android core - not give you possibility create that. If something like that created, will be very simple create virus which will send all calls recording to third party. Thats why it is not possible on android. Task is really complex. You can't run voip part(application) and gsm part(protected core task) at same time.